# MooTools - Handle none JSON response

Tags: ajax, mootools, xmlhttprequest

I use Request.Queue from more to fire my request one after one when the previous completes. Now I wonder how I should deal with requests that doesn't return json-encoded data (ie when a request fails and the script prints warnings and such).

Currently the request.queue fails instead of moving on to the next and I wonder how to catch that "error".

Comment: How do you instantiate your Requests? Are just some of the JSON-requests?

Comment: "...just some of __them__ JSON-requests"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by checking the response from the server using:

```
onComplete: function(resp) {
    if ($chk(resp))
        alert('It\'s woooorking!');
}
```